Azure Func: execution delays on consumption plans
I have the following function app running on consumption plan:

Using http trigger I start the process, the trigger starts long running orchestration

Orchestration + activity triggers syncs data (gets data from one system and sends it to another system). Each activity reads and processes only some amount of data sequentially to not hit the consumption plan limits.

Just in case after every page is processed we artificially apply idle period in orchestrator (30 seconds) and to make sure we not hit the limits.


The whole process lasts usually for 15-20 hours.
First 1-2 run results were expected - app processed all data without any unexpected delays.
Then some strange things began - according to the log (App Insights)
Every ~20 minutes, the app just hangs for ~8 minutes and does nothing.
For example, page was processed at 10:00:00, app waited for 30 seconds and next page began processing at 10:08:00.
Then for 20 minutes again every seemed normal until 10:28:00, app hangs again until 10:36:00
Is this expected on the consumption plan?
I don't see any errors in log or anything else that some limits reached - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox
I also checked metrics for the app.

Connections - app uses ~50-60 (limit is 600)

I don't create any threads inside the app or use scaling - so I believe threads should not be any issue. Anyway metrics shows - up to 100 in different periods of time (limit is 512)

Memory working set shows ~800 MB during processing

Based on metrics function execution count a day is ~15k calls.

This app is the only one on this consumption plan


I am confused. Any suggestions?
Update1: Now I am seeing thing in log.
Why host has been stopped in the middle of my process?
Is consumption plan is buggy or something?

Thank you!

One update: started another session today. The process lasted for 12 hours with no delay . Then another session for 12 hour - right after the previous one. It was active for 15 minutes and not it just idle for 10 hours already. No logs, just looked through Instances table with Storage explorer - there is one active (Running) orchestrator there. Is there any guarantee that the process will run without delays. The app is within the limits. It's insane...

Manually restarted the app and it continued where it left off... Does anyone know what it could be? I am using Serilog to output logs to file and app insights... nothing in there, just silence. All metrics are also were indicating that the app was idle but there were jobs in Instances table

The Consumption plan has an idle timeout of around 20 minutes, after which instances are recycled. This aligns with the ~20-minute intervals you're observing for the hangs or delays. The artificial 30-second idle periods you've introduced may not be enough to keep the instances alive.
For long-running processes or scenarios where you need more control over the hosting environment, the Azure Functions Premium plan might be a better fit. The Premium plan provides perpetually warm instances and avoids cold starts or unexpected restarts.

@alex, thanks for the info
Do instances recycle if the app is idle or even if app is doing something (orchestrators/child activities are running)?
30second artificial idle period is not for keeping instances warm, but to lower the connections mainly, to not hit the limit.
In general, cold starts are not an issue in my case, I am a bit worried that during my process (which can last for 8 hours) on consumption plan my orchestrator just hangs (sometimes for 10 minutes, sometimes for 1 hour, even 9 hours once...) and I need to check it in logs from time to time to be sure it is doing the job :(

I agree with @alex Consumption plan has a default limit of 10 minutes and it gets timed out after that interval. In order to run your Durable orchestrated functions continuously you can make use of Azure Function app Premium or App service Dedicated plan.

As Azure Functions Premium plan contains:-
Always ready instance and no delay in starting the function. It contains pre-warmed instances which reduces cold start. Also the timeout of Premium plan can be set to Unlimited and default value is set to 30 minutes.
Refer this Ms document for the comparison.
Additionally, In order to receive more insights on your Function app performance, Visit Diagnose and Solve Problems section and check Risk assessment, Availability and Performance:-



Do you mean "default limit of 10 minutes" for activity functions? Or orchestrators as well? I am aware of 10 minute timeouts for activity functions only - all my code is splitted into chunks to process every chunk in activity functions within 10 min limit. But my orchestrator should be busy for at least 8 hours. Basically there is a foreach loop for N number of chunks that are processed in activity, then artificially wait for 30 secs (context.CreateTimer call - to not hit consumption limits, mainly connections limit) and continue the orchestration.

My expectation is that orchestrator will do it's job (again, which should last for 8 hours) without any hangs/unexpected delays - of course IF my app does not hit any consumption limits (like memory, connections, threads and so on). But sometimes I see that on some orchestrator's iteration app just hangs for some period (sometimes it's 10 minutes, sometimes 20 mins, it was even 1 hour once..). Which is not expected of course, because this delays are not described anywhere in logs (at least I haven't found it)

The Function app consumption time out is for all the orchestrator and activities in your function trigger

But how then orchestrator can process data for hours and even days then?

Premium plan  has always ready instance that will keep your orchestrator and activity to start without any delay for a long time

Yes, premium plan is pretty straightforward :), but I am on consumption plan and will be using consumption onwards. How orchestrator works in consumption plan when it needs to process data for 20 mins for example? Let's say orchestrator contains 5 activities - 1st activity processes data for 5 mins, 2nd - 4mins, 3rd - 4mins, both 4th and 5th - for 3 mins each. So, in total orchestrator will be up for 5 + 4 + 4 + 3 + 3 = 19 minutes which is more than 10 max timeout period we can configure in host.json. The question is: will orchestrator fail in the middle of the process due to timeout? Thanks!

It should not fail in this case
